# Serialization of ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to serialize an ArrayList but when I deserialize I get all null values returned. Can't see why

```
public ArrayList<Uurwerken> maakUurwerk() {
    lijst.add(new PolsAnaloog(time, "roze", false, "PA01"));
    lijst.add(new PolsDigitaalTimer(time, "zwart", true, "PDT01"));
    lijst.add(new PolsAnaloog(time, "rood", false, "PA02"));
    lijst.add(new PolsAnaloogDatum(time, "zwart", true, "PAD01"));
        lijst.add(new PolsDigitaalDatumTimer(time, "groen", true, "PADT01"));
    lijst.add(new Wandklok(time, 10, 20, "geel", "Wand01"));
    lijst.add(new Wandklok(time, 50, 30, "wit", "Wand02"));
    lijst.add(new Wandklok(time, 5, 15, "blauw", "Wand03"));
    lijst.add(new Wandklok(time, 60, 60, "bruin", "Wand04"));
    lijst.add(new Wandklok(time, 80, 100, "wit", "Wand05"));
    return lijst;}
```

To perform the serialization I have following code:

```
public SerialOutput() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void schrijfLijstWeg(ArrayList<Uurwerken> klok) {
    FileOutputStream bestand = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        bestand = new FileOutputStream(Dir.PAD_Serial);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bestand);
        out.writeObject(klok);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Er is iets verkeerds gelopen bij het wegschrijven");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<Uurwerken> leesLijst() {
    FileInputStream bestand = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    ArrayList<Uurwerken> klokLijst = new ArrayList<Uurwerken>();
    try {
        bestand = new FileInputStream(Dir.PAD_Serial);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(bestand);
        klokLijst = (ArrayList<Uurwerken>) in.readObject();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Er is iets verkeerd gelopen met het inlezen");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return klokLijst;
}

public void toonUurwerk(ArrayList<Uurwerken> uurwerk) {
    Iterator<Uurwerken> it = uurwerk.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
}
```

Main contains following code

```
public static void main(String[]args){
Fabriek f = new Fabriek();
Serializatie so = new Serializatie();
    ArrayList <Uurwerken> list  = new ArrayList<Uurwerken>();
    list.addAll(f.maakUurwerk());
    so.schrijfLijstWeg(list);
    ArrayList<Uurwerken> temp = so.leesLijst();
    so.toonUurwerk(temp);
}
```

I tried to run so.toonUurwerk(list) and then I do get the right values. So I pressume it does serialize ok; but goes wrong in deserilization. Like said, when I run so.toonUurwerk it comes back with all 'null' values.

Comment: and your question is... ?

Comment: What exactly comes back from serialisation, could you further explain "stock adresses"

Comment: p.s. this would be much easier to follow if it wasn't in dutch

Comment: You may also way to call `so.toonUurwerk(f.maakUurwerk());` before serialization to check that `f.maakUurwerk()` really is what you think it is

Comment: "Stock addresses"? Does your class `Uurwerk` override `toString`? If not, it will display as something like `Uurwerk@4efc3a`.

Comment: @RichardTingle - not everyone's native language is English.

Comment: @Gorb unquestionably true.  However the OP clearly speaks english, as do the people who can answer the OPs question

Comment: The OP can speak/write English, but there's a difference between that and a mastery of the language required to parse an entire class to English. Most of the Java classes are written in English, you could just as well substitute the names for foo, bar, etc. Just saying, it's not an inordinate amount of effort. And if it is, people won't read it and he'll know better next time :)

Comment: Maybe we could stay on topic here instead of arguing about my native language

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is here:

```
list.addAll(f.maakUurwerk());
```

And:

```
public ArrayList<Uurwerken> maakUurwerk() {
    lijst.add(new PolsAnaloog(time, "roze", false, "PA01"));
```

As `maakUurwerk()` is not *creating* the List it is returning. Is this List a global variable? Has it been created/instantiated?

If not, this method is probably returning **null**, which means you're serialising **null**, and that's why it's printing out **null**!

Comment: If you mean have tried putting the List static, yes I have. The List as well as the method I tried putting static, but no change. The List is initialized in de constructor of Fabriek(). Anymore suggestions?